# Ramsey's Theorem(Numerical Example)

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Can anybody explain me 7x1 case of R(3,4) = 9(K9, complete graph with 9 vertexes)
 [Ramsey Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers). Look for table.
What's 7x1...

> Suppose the edges of a complete graph on 9 vertices are coloured red and blue. Pick a vertex, v. There are 8 edges incident to v and so (by the pigeonhole principle) at least 4 of them must be the same colour.
>   Which follows the following cases:
>   4x4, 5x3, 6x2, 7x1, 8x0.

And in general for any **odd** solution of R(s,r), how the (n-2)x1 case goes,
In fact, for K5 not to be a solution(but K9 is a solution), for 3x1 case, I gave myself the reason that,

> If the 5th vertex of set tries to make an edge with any of the other vertex then that other vertex going to have two edges with that color and hence contradicting the condition. Give that the disjoint subset of 2 vertexes of other 4 vertexes are already connected.

The post is little convoluted, can't find another way to put it.
Thanks.

**Edit**
First, I wanna mention that i'm developing an intuition as beginner, I did not started with proofs yet.
Okay, le'me rephrase it, let there are 9 vertexes.
Now, Specifically for 7x1 case, there are 4 pairs of vertex are colored with, let's say red color, now if I try to make an edge with the 9th vertex to any of the other 8, it'll cause 2 red colored edge for that vertex which doesn't falls under the case of 7x1, I mean how 7x1 case pass, if we are doing it via **Proof by cases**.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question just how to show that $R(3,4)=9$? If so you don't need to consider the case in question of $7,1$.

Instead of colouring red and blue and finding complete induced subgraphs, I will just use one colour, and instead find cliques and independent sets.

Clearly we know that $R(3,4) \geq 9$ since for example the cycle $C_8$ with vertices distance $4$ apart adjacent contains no $K_3$ and for each vertex the set of it's non-neighbours induces a $P_4$, which contains no independent set of size $3$ and so the graph cannot contain an independent set of size $4$.

Now let $G$ be a graph on $9$ vertices and let $v$ be a vertex of $G$. As you stated we use the pigeonhole principle and first assume that $v$ has at least $4$ neighbours in $G$, call them $a,b,c,d$. Since $R(2,4)=4$, the graph induced by $a,b,c,d$ either contains an edge (which together with $v$ forms a $K_3$ or an independent set of size $4$.

Next, assume that instead $v$ has at least $6$ non-neighbours. Then using the fact that $R(3,3)=6$, the subgraph induced by these non-neighbours either contains an independent set of size 3 (which along with $v$ forms an independent set of size $4$) or a clique of size 3 (an induced $K_3$).

Now the only case left to check is when $v$ has exactly $3$ neighbours, i.e. the degree of $3$ is exactly $3$. But as $v$ was chosen arbitrarily, all vertices of the graph $G$ have degree $3$, which is a contradiction by the Handshaking lemma as there are an odd number of vertices of odd degree, hence we are done.

Comment: can you pick approach from edit and build your argument. Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but in that case it's just a subset of the one I described before, with at least $4$ adjacent vertices adjacent to $v$. So say $v$ has $7$ red neighbours, then we know that $R(2,7)=7$, so we can either find a red edge on these $7$ neighbours, in which case we form a red $K_3$ or we can find a blue $K_7$, in particular we can find a blue $K_4$.

Comment: Or, i might not understood some point in there, so can you tell me and help me with that too. Thanks.

Comment: Which part do you not understand, that might help :)

Comment: Okay, bear with me, i'll try to explain you step-by-step, If i'm doing proof via **Proof by case** of R(3,4) which equals 9. We established that. Now, that means(this is my understanding, correct me if i'm wrong), that every vertex will connect to every other 8 vertex, among which 7 are of same color(say, red) and 1 is of say, blue. For _7x1_ case.

Comment: And since i'm doing proof via, **Proof by cases**, i need to proof, _4x4_ , _5x3_ , _6x2_ , _7x1_ , holds. Now, what i'm saying is, 4 vertexes will pair with other 4 vertex with blue edge. which left-out the one vertex(say, x). Now, when this vertex, **x** tries to make a blue edge(since, for _7x1_ , case every vertex should have 7-red edge and 1-blue edge.), with any of the other vertex, it leads for that other vertex to have two blue edges, which violates our condition for case, _7x1_ . Is there something wrong with my understanding here?!! I mean there must be, coz it's the solution.

Comment: $R(3,4)$ is the _smallest_ number of vertices $n$, on which no matter which colouring of the complete graph $K_{n}$ we take, we can either find a red $K_3$ between $3$ of these $n$ vertices OR a blue $K_4$ between these $n$ vertices. Now what you are saying (or what I believe you are saying) is that _every_ vertex of the graph has 7 neighbours of the same colour. This is not what you are supposed to do. You should just consider an _arbitrary_ vertex of the graph with say $7$ say red neighbours and $1$ blue neighbour. Where did you find this question, have you studied this topic?

Comment: I'm studying this topic(Ramsey's Theorem) for like 2-days. Actually i'm studying Proofs from MIT lecture series, in there book they explain R(3,3), under the name **friends and strangers** with **Proofs by cases**. So, I tried to prove it for R(3,4) and here we are.  And what i'm saying is _every_ vertex of the graph has 8 neighbors, with 7 of one color and 1 of other color, if we consider 2-colouring graph.

Comment: Ok I will try to take more of a general approach to the explanation. So I previously defined what the Ramsey number $R(3,4)$ is in my previous comment. When we consider cases, we need only consider a _single_ vertex $v$ of the graph $G$ on $9$ vertices. Now to apply cases as you wish to do so, we need only consider the neighbours on this one vertex $v$, as it was chosen arbitrarily. The aim from here is to show that in each case, we can find either a red $K_3$ or a blue $K_4$ in $G$.

Comment: Okay, i've chosen a single arbitrary vertex _v_. Now, what what do you mean by _The aim from here is to show in **each case**_. Can you elaborate on **each.**

Comment: Well the way I described it in my original answer does approach by cases, but bunches the cases together. So I first consider where the vertex $v$ has $4$ or more say red edges adjacent to it, and then consider the case where it has $6$ or more blue edges adjacent to $v$. After these two case are done, there is only the case with exactly $3$ red adjacent edges left, which I also showed how to approach in the answer given.